# Limit the number of sql queries executions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008

I have implemented a web service (C#) that executes the queries on SQL Server. I want to limit number of executions to prevent attack to SQL server (eg. one execution in 20 secs). How to do that?

Comment: Limit per user? or limit for the whole application?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you [limit the number of concurrent connections on the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030.aspx)? Using SQL Server. It will handle concurrency for you so you won't get the database flooded.
If you are using WCF you can also implement [throthling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116799/wcf-service-for-many-concurrent-clients-and-database-access). [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and) explains the different approaches to concurrency using WCF (Single, Multiple and Reentrant).
On Single, only one request will be processed by the web service at once and consequently on the database at once. On Multiple you will have multiple threads being processed, but combined with Throttling you will be able to limit the number of concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to check the request in service layer, block the request which coming with high frequency by using IP or some other information